# Discord.Js - Get a list of all user's sent messages?

Tags: node.js, collections, discord, discord.js

Im writing a Discord bot using Discord.js in node and wondering if there is anyway to get a array or collection of all a users messages. Ive tried looking through some of the member collections and can't seem to find anything. Would be great help thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm assuming you are using Discord.js Version 12.0.2. You can do this with a function, which needs the parameters guildID (the guild's ID) and the userID (the member you want all messages from)
>
> Then you want to fetch as many messages you want in every channel. The maximum you can is 100.
>
> We now filter all the fetched messages if the message#author.id is equal to the userID parameter.
>
> whatever you want to do, goes after. msgs are the filtered messages. you could for example log all the content of the messages, with their channel to the console (thats, what I did)

```
async function userMessages(guildID, userID){
    client.guilds.cache.get(guildID).channels.cache.forEach(ch => {
        if (ch.type === 'text'){
            ch.messages.fetch({
                limit: 100
            }).then(messages => {
                const msgs = messages.filter(m => m.author.id === userID)
                msgs.forEach(m => {
                    console.log(`${m.content} - ${m.channel.name}`)
                })
            })
        } else {
            return;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Note that this will be limited to going through 100 messages per channel unless you combine a loop and the `before` option in fetching the messages.